# htaccess client index mode rewrite help

Tags: .htaccess

I need help for my site for custom domain, let me explain:

I have links:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?x=CLIENT_INDEX_1/TEMPLATE_LINK1
www.mysite.com/index.php?x=CLIENT_INDEX_1/TEMPLATE_LINK2

www.mysite.com/index.php?x=CLIENT_INDEX_2/TEMPLATE_LINK1
....
```

CLIENT_INDEX or TEMPLATE_LINK can be everything, CLIENT_INDEX represent client template, TEMPLATE_LINK is template link.
and I made mode rewrite rule in htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?x=$1 [L,QSA]
```

now I have nice URLs: www.mysite.com/CLIENT_INDEX_2/CLIENT_LINK1

One client ask me can he buy domain, link to mine and it will opening his template:
example: 
client who index is CLIENT_INDEX_1 bought: example.com, now links look:

```
www.example.com/TEMPLATE_LINK1
www.example.com/TEMPLATE_LINK2
```

I know that CLIENT_INDEX is not folder and it is only GET variable, but how can I set when someone open his link (www.example.com) that system will overwride CLIENT_INDEX suffix?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

And later get the requested URL in PHP with **$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]**.