# Static php pages from database

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, templates

I surfed all around the internet and i couldn`t find an answer for my problem..so i ask You :)

I want to navigate, in my website, to pages in that format: `http://example.com/category/page.php` (eg: `http://example.com/action/login.php`)
instead of:  `http://example.com/index.php?action=login`

And all the data of a page to be stored in mysql database instead of creating hundreds of .html or .php files by myself. I need just one page with a template model where data will be shown...

Is there any way to transform the dynamic links into static links unisng data from mysql database?

Please give me an explain whats with the .htaccess file...i couldn't understand how to deal with it...

Comment: Don't use real domain names as examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite - Send everything that doesn't exist to index.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713973/mod-rewrite-send-everything-that-doesnt-exist-to-index-php), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243709/apache-mod-rewrite-route-everything-to-index-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858570/htaccess-client-index-mode-rewrite-help

Answer (score 0):

Create folders with category names in the place where you have index.php
Then inside those folders, put your php files.

For example, `login.php` would be inside folder `action`.

If you don't want to have the files and folders, then you will need to revise your desired url, for example:

```
http://example.com/action.php?page=login.php
```

or

```
http://example.com/?cat=action&page=login.php
```

or

```
http://example.com/?script=action/login.php
```